# how to uninstall perl on linux

Tags: linux, perl, uninstallation

I just installed perl on linux referring to http://learn.perl.org/installing/unix_linux.html

Using the command: `curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ranguard/installing-perl/master/scripts/install_perl_on_nix.sh | bash`

Does anyone know how to remove the perl? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't you like it?

```
rm -rf ~/perl5
```

Then edit your `~/.bashrc` file and find the line that says `source /home/yourlogin/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` and delete it.

Comment: When I typed "perl -v", the version is: "This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 4 (v5.14.4) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi". SO does it mean I should use "rm -rf ~/perl14"?

Comment: No. The script you quoted above installs the current version to `~/perl5`.

Comment: I tried, but it seems doesn't work. I can still use perl -v command

Comment: @FreyaRen all unix-like systems (which includes Linux) have a perl installed; you should *not* uninstall that. The system perl executable usually resides in `/usr/bin/perl`. You can test which executable is used by the `perl` command by typing `which perl` into the terminal. It will print the whole path. If it is the path of the system perl, everything is OK.

Comment: @innaM Now everytime I typed "su" and go to the root, I get this warning  "bash: /root/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc: No such file or directory". I think that is because I execute "rm -rf ~/perl5". Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score -3):

Try quering for perl rpm

```
rpm -qa | grep "perl"
```

and then, remove all references of perl using

```
rpm -e <above list>
```

Comment: How is RPM related to this question?

Comment: I try to list all libraries related to Perl, but I got perl-libs as well as perl-module, I don't know which should I remove

Comment: @kirelagin.. i think perl rpm would be installed subsequently when you issue that command. What do you think otherwise..

Comment: @Freya Ren.. did you try to query via rpm command to fetch that list

Comment: Yes, I could fetch the list starting with "Perl". But I have no idea which to remove

Comment: @FreyaRen,,, can you paste the list here.

Comment: @DennyMathew because I checked the installation script and it seems to me that it has nothing to do with RPM.